# About the Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use the Python Selenium to make some web automation.
For now, I can get all the href from the web.

The question is I'm trying to get the href only the [i class="icon as--c like btn_icon" ] [span]number[/span]  <-- the number is >= 1 if there is no number it won't get the href

[this is the code with number >= 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXTaJ.png)

[this is the code with no number in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMw9J.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("")   # link
for i in range(1,10):
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
    time.sleep(2)
class_name = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tile__covershot")
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in class_name]

for link in links:
    print(link)
```

Comment: It may be easier to get all the href elements and loop through them to get the matching spans

Comment: You shared the same images, please check the files.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [relative xpath](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html#4) to get what you wanted. On your case, something like this

```js
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("")   # link
for i in range(1,10):
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
    time.sleep(2)
elem_with_number_xpath = "(//span[contains(text(),'1')]|//span[contains(text(),'2')]|//span[contains(text(),'3')]|//span[contains(text(),'4')]|//span[contains(text(),'5')]|//span[contains(text(),'6')]|//span[contains(text(),'7')]|//span[contains(text(),'8')]|//span[contains(text(),'9')])/ancestor::div[2]/preceding::a[1]"

elems_with_number = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(elem_with_number_xpath)

links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems_with_number]

for link in links:
    print(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the ahref tags loop through them and check if they aren't empty or > 1 and if they are append to list.

```
elems=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//i[class='icon as--c like btn_icon']/span/ancestor::div[2]/preceding::a[1]")
lst=[]
for elem in elems:
    val=elem.find_element_by_xpath('//i/span')
    if len(val.text)!=0:
        if int(val.text)>1:
            lst.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
```